# Nested if to check if one or more pandas column satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a DF which looks as follows

```
customer   activity_1  activity_2  activity_3 activity_4 
    1         40         null        30         null
    2         41         null       null        null
    3         60          50         60          75
    4        null        null       null        null
    5        null         20         40          10
```

Question1:
Now I need to add a column using a nested if function to return 0 if all the activites are null, 1 if at least one activity is not null, 2 if at least two activities are not null, arriving to 4 if all activities are not null.

what i have tried to far to solve it is:

```
def act(x):
    if (x['activity_1'] != 'null'):
         return 1
    elif (x['activity_1'] != 'null') & (x['activity_2'] != 'null'):
        return 2
    elif (x['activity_1'] != 'null') & (x['activity_2'] != 'null') & (x['activity_3'] != 'null'):
        return 3
    elif (x['activity_1'] != 'null') & (x['activity_2'] != 'null') & (x['activity_3'] != 'null') & (x['activity_4'] != 'null'):
        return 4
    else:
       return 0
```

Then:

```
df['act'] = df.apply(act, axis=1)
```

Question2:
Add a column with the name of the activities that are present in each case.

What i have tried so far is to define another nested if function which checks if in the new column act the value is 1 the return activity 1 and so on

Many Thanks!

Comment: What I've you tried so far ? It seems that you want us to write code for you..

Comment: I will add the code to the question

Comment: question updated, sorry for the mislead

Comment: Thx ;), downvote removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sum` and `join` with mask to get the count of null for specific range of columns and the column names of not null columns i.e

```
#Question 1
df["sum"] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(row[1:5]=='null') ,axis=1)

#Question 2
mask = (df[df.columns[1:5]]!='null')
df["activity"] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(mask.columns[row[1:5]!='null']),axis=1)
```

You can also use :

```
df["sum"] = df.iloc[:,1:].eq('null').sum(axis=1)

df['activity'] = df.iloc[:,1:5].ne('null').apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[1:5][x]), axis=1)
```

Ouptut :

```
   customer activity_1 activity_2 activity_3 activity_4  sum  \
0         1         40       null         30       null    2   
1         2         41       null       null       null    3   
2         3         60         50         60         75    0   
3         4       null       null       null       null    4   
4         5       null         20         40         10    1   

                                      activity  
0                        activity_1,activity_3  
1                                   activity_1  
2  activity_1,activity_2,activity_3,activity_4  
3                                               
4             activity_2,activity_3,activity_4  
In [1310]:
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Glad to help sir!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a <strike>one</strike> three liner, first converting your "null" strings into `numpy.NaN` values:

```
# Assuming your dataframe is already created and assigned to `df`
import numpy as np
df = df.replace("null", np.NaN)
df = df.assign(count_null=lambda x: 4 - x.isnull().sum(axis=1))
```

Notes:

- Use `assign` to create a new column, named `count_null` but change to whatever you like.
- I've hardcoded 4 as the number of columns, so you might want to make this dynamic if the DF will change shape
- Using the lambda's assignment of the DF to `x`, we're using the `.isnull` method to summarise the columns to True / False depending on whether contents are null.
- Sum the result, using `axis=1` to go horizontally across the rows instead of the default vertical, Series approach.

**Edit**: I've added the code to convert the "null" string to a `NaN` value, which would allow you to do other built-in Pandas calculations that take into account null values. If the DataFrame gets larger, these operations are likely to be quicker than string comparisons.

Comment: 'null' is a string here how can use use `isnull()`?

Comment: @Bharathshetty ah, missed that. Have updated with an alternative that makes use of the NaN / null behaviour for future reference.